# bind textbox to a field of a query of dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, binding, dataset

I have a Stored Procedure which returns either one or no rows (0-1 rows), and I use DataSet so I add my stored procedure to my dataset then I call it.
Now I want to bind a textbox's Text property to a field of the returning row, how can I do that?

Comment: Get the value out from the field and assign it to the `TextBox`, now where are you stuck in this ?

Comment: I'm using an ObjectDataSource connected to my DataSet, how can I Get the value out of my ObjectDataSource @V4Vendetta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
 textbox.text=DtSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["database column name"].ToString();
```